# Nine months into a new job and I want to quit. How can I improve the situation?

Tags: software-industry, colleagues, project-management, software-development

I am having a lot of difficulties at my job. I liked it for the first six months and now I hate it and want to quit.

I am an intermediate web developer at a large company making an internal product that will eventually be released to some customers, but there is no hard deadline. There are four of us working on the project and one very hands-off manager.

Here are the problems:

**Daily schedule**: Every Monday, Wednesday and Friday we have a meeting after lunch for about 30 mins. As I work 9-5 with an hour lunch break I find this to be a really inconvenient time for a meeting because it forces you to take a lunch break at a certain time and it can be disruptive to what you are working on. Also, after lunch time I feel tired, and I don’t really feel prepared to do a meeting after coming back from a break.

We cannot really change the meeting times because the people we meet with are in another time zone.

Unnecessary meetings:

As I am a developer and want to focus on my code and tickets there’s not much sense in me sitting in a meeting for 30+ minutes listening to others talk about things unrelated to my tickets or my immediate priorities. I feel that it gets in the way of my productivity. It would be better if only developers met to talk about the project architecture.

1.5-2 hours wasted every Monday, Wednesday and Friday

**No structure or expectation**s:
Sometimes I go into work, and I have no idea what my priorities should be so I spend about 1-2 hours in the morning trying to talk to my team members to get a sense of what I should be focusing on. By the time they suggest something for me to work on I feel tired from the debate and want to take a break.

Half of the time they don’t know or have an idea of what I should be doing. The project manager doesn’t help me either.

I’ve tried to send everyone an email asking for what my priorities should be for the day or week, but I haven’t got much success. It always ends up being a biweekly 1-2 hour debate and then my priorities always seem to shift.

**Difficult coworkers**:

If I don’t complete a ticket to my coworker’s satisfaction he is extremely critical of me. He’s quite mean about it, but in my defense it’s hard to get things perfect with the exhausting unstructured chaotic workflow.

My coworkers are not good at vocalizing important news, updates or ideas for the project.

They expect me to spend about 30 minutes to an hour looking through their chat message logs instead of sending an email or having a short meeting or conversation with all of us. It infuriates me. It’s not an efficient way to communicate.

I’ve expressed this to them, but they just say too bad and expect me to check the chat messages and every notification that comes up on the chat board. There are even non-work related things on the chat board, and it takes too much of my time to sift out any important updates.

They get really offended if I express any frustration or negative feelings about work at all. For example, I was told that I had to re-do something for the 5th time because they decided to change something else in the project so naturally I was irritated. They say that this is an ‘attitude’. Well, who wouldn’t be frustrated if you were told that you’ll probably have to re-do something AGAIN.

While this is not really work related, I don’t really click with my coworkers or communicate well with them. We don’t seem to be on the same page about the project.

Sometimes my coworkers take my tickets without telling me. It’s really frustrating when you’ve invested mental energy into something only to have someone take it from under your feet.

My coworkers don’t like it when I work at home. They feel that working at home is slacking off. Management does it all the time because they have kids. I have a kid too, but my two critical coworkers don’t.

**Hands off management**:

The project manager has his own project to worry about and ours is just an aside for him, so he’s not really that invested in it and doesn’t know what’s going on.

What could I do to help improve this situation? It’s driving me crazy.
Should I talk to management?

Comment: It sounds like your team could benefit from transitioning into an agile team; it would help with the meeting lengths and structured expectations. If you do not already have one-on-one meetings with your manager, I suggest setting up a meeting to talk about some of these issues and ask for suggestions. They will know your team members best and can help with navigating the social dynamic.

Comment: How did you even manage to like this terrible environment for 6 months.  You get I am suggesting that maybe your attitude it the problem?

Comment: @Paparazzi well I am trying my best to try to fix the problems but I feel so frustrated and dissatisfied with the job.

Comment: why can't you use the meetings to work out what work you should be prioritising?

Comment: exhausting and chaotic but you don't know what to do most of the time so you're doing nothing, but you don't have time for meetings, time wasted... the whole question makes little sense to me it contradicts itself all over the place. I think you need to restructure it.

Comment: In these situations you need people outside of your work that can give you what you are not getting at your work place.  This can help give you the strength to face these types of challenges.

Comment: 3 meeting/week is overkill, that should be reduced to 1 meeting. No definition of priorities, no roadmaps, no distribution of work, no concept of ownership of problems....What do you talk in meeting, about the weather? I think the problem is not you, but lack of management and guidance.

Comment: You seem to be pointing the finger quite angrily at everyone but yourself, are you perfect? Take a step back and stop looking at the problems, but look at the room for improvement and make it happen.

Answer (score 5):

### Improve the situation by changing your expectations and your attitude.

No matter what you are feeling on the inside, you should be projecting a happy, confident, and content demeanor at work.  This is one of the defining characteristics of professionalism.

> I was told that I had to re-do something for the 5th time because they
>   decided to change something else in the project so naturally I was
>   irritated. They say that this is an ‘attitude’. Well, who wouldn’t be
>   frustrated if you were told that you’ll probably have to re-do
>   something AGAIN.

I might be frustrated, but I would do my best not to let it show.  My employer is compensating me for my time.  If they want me to do something *50 times* that is their prerogative.

**The only thing worse than working a frustrating task on a small team is working a frustrating task on a small team with someone who won't stop complaining.**  We're all in the same boat.  Unless your have something constructive to offer, quit your bitching and get back to rowing.

### Be more proactive about solving your problems.

There is another way to characterize what you describe as unstructured and chaotic.  You could instead say that you have a lot of freedom and leeway to make your own decisions.  You can use that freedom to tackle some of the more practical complaints you have.  For example:

> Sometimes I go into work and I have no idea what my priorities should
>   be so I spend about 1-2 hrs in the morning trying to talk to my team
>   members to get a sense of what I should be focusing on. By the time
>   they suggest something for me to work on I feel tired from the debate
>   and want to take a break.

This sounds like freedom to me.  Pick what ***you*** think is most important and work on that.  Communicate your intentions clearly to the team before you get started.  Tell them that unless they direct you otherwise you will be working on X,Y,Z today.  **Make sure you do this in writing,** so that you don't have to take the blame later when the mismanagement becomes evident to your boss' boss.

Speaking of your boss:

> Sometimes my coworkers take my tickets without telling me. It’s really
>   frustrating when you’ve invested mental energy into something only to
>   have someone take it from under your feet.

You really need to talk to your manager about this.  Whoever is taking your tickets and not marking them in the system is wasting your time and the company's resources.  They need to have this behavior corrected.  Don't allow this to continue without complaining.